# Is NeuraSan effective for smoking cessation?

Tags: smoking

The [NeuraSan website](http://www.neurasan.de/index.php?locale=en) describes a treatment to help give up smoking:

> The method uses specific treatment procedures that are derived from
>   the areas of naturopathy, homeopathy, and findings of internal
>   medicine

It involves "ear injection therapy".

Is there evidence that the NeuraSan treatment is effective?

Comment: A standard warning: It is dangerous to assume that a homeopathic remedy contains no active ingredients. Some dosages do include active ingredients, and the medication may not be properly regulated to ensure it is prepared in accordance with the label.

Comment: I'm seeing absolutely nothing in terms of reviews/testimonials available from outside the controlled domain.  It doesn't pass the smell test for me, but I've got nothing.  There are other "smoking vaccines" that were available, and many of them seem shady (and in one case a guy went to jail for fraud over it) but I don't know how similar those were to whatever NuraSan is offering.

Comment: I don't think something pitched by one commercial site, with no credible references, qualifies as a "notable claim".

Comment: "Ear injection therapy", according to the one page on the website, means that a needle injects your earlobe with whatever the NeuraSan mixture is (the website has an ingredients page too, but doesn't actually list any ingredients).